# MVC 5 Conditional Validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5

Once again plethora of similar questions and none I can find to help me, or one I can understand.

My struggle is very simple actually. In a register form , I need to validate a few fields IF country selected from a drop down is a specific one. If not , no additional validations are needed. Let's say the country code needs to be "XX" in order to check the fields for things like length, integer or not etc.

I'm very new to MVC (less than a week) and after working with Webforms for a while, even something this simple confuses me. Anyway, here my code pieces

RegisterViewModel(only relevant fields included)

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        //

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Ülke")]
        public string CountryCode {get; set;}

        //

        //[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Posta Kodu")]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "İrtibat E-Mail Adresi")]
        public string Email { get; set; }


        //regular expression and string length validations should work only if a certain country is selected
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$")]
        [StringLength(11, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Vergi Numarası      hatalı.<br/> Lütfen kontrol ediniz.")]
        [Display(Name = "Vergi No")]
        public string TaxIdNo { get; set; }

        //

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Firma Yetkilisi T.C. Kimlik Numarası")]
        public string UserCitizenIdNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Firma Yetkilisi Email")]
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Firma Yetkilisi Tel. No.")]
        public string UserPhoneNumber { get; set; }

       //

    }
```

The country dropdown

```
@Html.Bootstrap().DropDownListFor(t => t.CountryCode, MVCUtility.DataTableToListItem((DataTable)ViewBag.CountryList, "Code", "Name")).HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:100%;" })
```

I came across HasSelfValidation on a question but sadly noticed it is retired. How can I make these work inside an if-like construct?

PS: We set the dropdown to a specific value, I need to check if it's changed or not too.

Comment: Consider using one of the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) conditional validation attributes (otherwise [write your own](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2))

Comment: I can already control the length and "only integers", I just need to put the validations inside an "if" so they work only in a specific condition. I thought this would be something simple, do I really need to write my own validation?

Comment: If one of the foolproof validation attributes do not suit your needs - e.g. `[RequiredIf("CountryCode", "XX")]public string Email { get; set; }`, then yes you do unless you can find other suitable libraries. You can also consider using [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc) rather than validation attributes

Comment: And looking at the model in your question, then all you do need is the `RequiredIfAttribute`

Comment: Field will always be required, additional validation will be required only if a certain country is selected. Wouldn't requiredif challenge the always required condition?

Comment: But your code shows you don't have validation other that `[Required]` so not clear what your saying.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code now

Comment: ASFAIK, none of the foolproof attributes will meet you requirements.